# Python Error 104, connection reset by peer

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, python-requests

I have been having this error when trying to make web requests to various hosts. After debugging a bit I have found the solution is updating the requests[security] through pip.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Run

`python3 -m pip install "requests[security]"`

or

`python -m pip install "requests[security]"`

to fix this issue.

Comment: You really shouldn't advocate using pip as root, though

Answer (score 5):

I was running into this issue as well with Python2.7 requests. Installing
`"requests[security]"` with pip brought a clear improvement for me but out of 1000 requests in rapid succession, I would still get this error 2 or 3 times.

Resolved to implementing retries as this seems to be a very temporary issue. Works like a charm now.

```py
import time
import requests
from requests.exceptions import ConnectionError

# ...

nb_tries = 10
while True:
    nb_tries -= 1
    try:
        # Request url
        result = session.get("my_url")
        break
    except ConnectionError as err:
        if nb_tries == 0:
            raise err
        else:
            time.sleep(1)

# ...
```