# python error 104 Connection reset by peer

Tags: python, python-2.7, web-scraping, web-crawler, pyspider

I can't figure out why I keep getting this error or how to fix it. I've ran a bunch of different URL's and this error doesn't happen every time. Is it something I can fix or something in my code I can fix or is this something out of my power to fix??

I have looked on stack overflow and the stuff similar to my problem isn't working!!!!

Here is my code that I'm running using vagrant, and python 2.7 :

```
import urllib2
from urlparse import urljoin
from urlparse import urlparse
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
import socket


def check_web_health(root,max_depth):
    domain = get_domain(root)
    filter_domain = [domain]
    tocrawl = [[root,1]]
    crawled = {}
    count=0;
    while tocrawl:
        crawl_ele = tocrawl.pop()
        link = crawl_ele[0]
        depth = crawl_ele[1]

        if link not in crawled.keys():
            content, status = get_page(link)
            if content == None:
                crawled[link]= status
                continue
            host = get_domain(link)
            if depth < max_depth and host in filter_domain:
                outlinks = get_all_links(content,link)
                print '-----------------------------------'
                print 'Adding outlinks ' + str(outlinks) + ' for parent page '+link
                print '-----------------------------------'
                add_to_tocrawl(crawled.keys(),tocrawl, outlinks, depth+1)
            crawled[link]= status

    f = open('site_health.txt', 'w')
    for url,status in crawled.iteritems():
        f.write(url)
        f.write('\t')
        f.write('\t')
        f.write(status)
        f.write('\n')
    f.close()

def get_domain(url):
    hostname = urlparse(url).hostname
    if len(re.findall( r'[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+){3}', hostname)) > 0:
        return hostname
    elif len(hostname.split('.')) == 0:
        hostname
    elif hostname.find('www.') != -1:
        return hostname.split('.')[0]
    else:
        return hostname.split('.')[1]

def get_page(url):
    print url
    try:
        response = urllib2.urlopen(url)
        return response.read(), 'OK'
    except urllib2.HTTPError,e:
        return None, str(e.code)
    except urllib2.URLError,e:
        print e.args
        return None, 'Invalid Url'
    except:
        return None, 'Wrong Url'

def get_next_target(page,parent):
    start_link = page.find('<a href=')
    if start_link == -1:
        return None, 0
    start_quote = page.find('"', start_link)
    end_quote = page.find('"', start_quote + 1)
    url = page[start_quote + 1:end_quote]
    url = urljoin(parent,url)
    return url, end_quote

def get_all_links(page,parent):
    links = []
    while True:
        url, endpos = get_next_target(page,parent)
        if url:
            links.append(url)
            page = page[endpos:]
        else:
            break
    return links


def add_to_tocrawl(crawled, tocrawl, newlinks, depth):
    for link in newlinks:
        if link not in tocrawl and link not in crawled:
            tocrawl.append([link,depth])


check_web_health('https://www.chicagomaps.org',3) # put any URL from the internt here
```

Comment: Check this similar question it should help! [Python handling socket.error: \[Errno 104\] Connection reset by peer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20568216/python-handling-socket-error-errno-104-connection-reset-by-peer)

Comment: search a little before posting a question, yours is probably an exact duplicate of this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41832838/python-error-104-connection-reset-by-peer

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python handling socket.error: \[Errno 104\] Connection reset by peer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20568216/python-handling-socket-error-errno-104-connection-reset-by-peer)

Comment: I have seen those posts before and I tried them and I still get an error