# Python ('Connection aborted.', error(104, 'Connection reset by peer')) when trying to make a GET request to Telegram URLs

Tags: python, flask, networking, python-requests

I have a Telegram bot running on a DO box for a while now. And strangely, without any changes to the code or the server, the bot stopped working with `('Connection aborted.', error(104, 'Connection reset by peer'))` exceptions raised.

**Upon investigating, I found:**

1. GET requests to other services are working fine.
2. The exception is raised when it tries the following code block.

```py
...
    type_action = "https://api.telegram.org/bot{}/sendChatAction?chat_id={}&action=typing".format(telegram_bot_key, telegram_group_id)
    send_message = "https://api.telegram.org/bot{}/sendMessage?chat_id={}&text={}&parse_mode=html&reply_to_message_id={}".format(telegram_bot_key, telegram_group_id, t_message, message_id)
    try:
        requests.get(type_action)
        time.sleep(5)
        requests.get(send_message)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
...
```

**So far, I've troubleshot these:**

1. Verified that the bot is not rate limited by making a request locally.
2. The server is healthy with no resource limitations or any such incidents.
3. Tried `pip install "requests[security]"` as suggested by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41832839/1649171) answer.
4. Set the message sent to a shorter one - `test`.
5. Verified that no IPs are blocked by the firewall.

---

It is really strange that all GET requests to other API URLs work. And the same Telegram URL works when requested locally. But when the request happens from the above code-block, it throws the error in question.

I am stumped.

Comment: So, have you found the solution? It seems like they (Telegram) changed something in API in 2019. Have seen a few similar questions dating from 2019 to 2020.