# OpenSSL SSL_connect: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL in connection to api.telegram.org:443

Tags: ssl, openssl, telegram, telegram-bot

In my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58645747/python-connection-aborted-error104-connection-reset-by-peer-when-tryi) I was facing issues getting my Telegram webhook to work. And now, when I try to `curl` Telegram's `https://api.telegram.org` I'm getting `OpenSSL SSL_connect: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL in connection to api.telegram.org:443`.

The following is the verbose and response from the request.

```sh
curl -v https://api.telegram.org
* Rebuilt URL to: https://api.telegram.org/
*   Trying 149.154.167.220...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to api.telegram.org (149.154.167.220) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* OpenSSL SSL_connect: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL in connection to api.telegram.org:443
* stopped the pause stream!
* Closing connection 0
curl: (35) OpenSSL SSL_connect: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL in connection to api.telegram.org:443
```

How should I proceed? I have reinstalled and upgraded `OpenSSL`. Live migrated to a new hypervisor.

**Update:** Tested it with a new droplet. Same situation. [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0yWNP.png).

Comment: Source of the problem could be some DPI firewall blocking the connection. Have you tried with any other program (i.e. wget, browser, `openssl s_client`, ...) from the same system?

Comment: The wget request ended with `Unable to establish SSL connection.`

Comment: This suggests a similar problem. Again, this might be some DPI firewall blocking connections so you are probably out of luck unless you have some control over the network and can disable potential firewalls there (unclear where this firewall is, might also be way upstream).

Comment: I did check the firewall and added a rule to allow all GET requests to the telegram URL. I am still getting the same error.

Comment: It is unclear what you did exactly and if you've even addressed the correct firewall - 
 likely not. Depending on where you've live and work the problem might be a company firewall or might also be some device at a government controlled ISP.

Comment: All the servers I tried, belong to DigitalOcean. I tried three different regions and the results are the same. The first two tests were from Asia. The third one was from the USA region. The requests work locally on my home network though.

Comment: Strange, I have no problems accessing this from a VPS on DigitalOcean (USA SFO).

Comment: @SteffenUllrich, I created a new test droplet and tried requesting. I am getting the same error. Contacted DigitalOcean support about this. [Here](https://i.imgur.com/2Nph0TN.png) is a screenshot.